# Input box to paste found rows to new sheet

Tags: excel, search, inputbox, vba

I have what is working code but I want to be able to run it 2,3, 4 times and have it just keep moving down the destination sheet.  Instead it overwrites what the last pass pasted.

```
Sub Comparison_Entry()

Dim myWord$

myWord = InputBox("Enter UID, If no more UIDs, enter nothing and click OK",   "Enter User")
    If myWord = "" Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xRow&, NextRow&, LastRow&
NextRow = 1
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows,     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For xRow = 1 To LastRow
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(xRow), "*" & myWord & "*") > 0 Then
Rows(xRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(NextRow)
NextRow = NextRow + 1
End If
Next xRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Copyng complete, " & NextRow - 2 & " rows containing" & vbCrLf & _
"''" & myWord & "''" & " were copied to Sheet1.", 64, "Done"

End Sub``
```

I tried adding a loop to this but each pass through it would start over at the top of Sheet1. Similarly, if I simply call the Sub again I get the same result.

Comment: Opps, I think this row: 
 
    Rows(xRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(NextRow)

needs to be more like:  

    Rows(xRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(LastRow + 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would know what column to search through, such as what column is `UID`. in this example code I will assume it is column A of the active sheet, change the column letter to what suites you.

```
Sub Comparison_EntryB()

    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, s As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'change to column you need you search through
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(Rws, "A"))    'change to column you need to search through
    End With

    s = InputBox("enter Something")

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If UCase(c) Like "*" & UCase(s) & "*" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, the existing code allows me to search all columns though.  This way I can search by UID, Last Name, AD ID, Unit...etc

Comment: However, your code works perfectly when set as it is.

Comment: I adjusted the range to allow for columns A through L and it is still working as needed.  Thank you so much

Comment: 1 thing I would like to try though is I notice it is case sensitive.  Any way to make it not case sensitive?

Comment: Changed line to `If UCase(c) Like "*" & UCase(s) & "*" Then`, so If Upper case (c) = Upper Case "s", then do something.